# How can I change this code into an array?

Tags: flash

Any suggestions would be appreciated

```
tocProduction.alpha = 0;
tocWardrobe.alpha = 0;
tocMakeup.alpha = 0;
tocIllustrators.alpha = 0;
tocSpecialfx.alpha = 0;
tocAssisting.alpha = 0;
tocContact.alpha = 0;

tocProduction.x = 400;
tocWardrobe.x = 400;
tocMakeup.x = 400;
tocIllustrators.x = 400;
tocSpecialfx.x = 400;
tocAssisting.x = 400;
tocContact.x = 400;

TweenMax.to(tocProduction, .75, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocWardrobe, 1, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocMakeup, 1.25, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocIllustrators, 1.5, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocSpecialfx, 1.75, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocAssisting, 2, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});
TweenMax.to(tocContact, 2.25, {alpha:1, ease:Circ.easeIn});

tocProduction.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over);
tocWardrobe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over1);
tocMakeup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over2);
tocIllustrators.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over3);
tocSpecialfx.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over4);
tocAssisting.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over5);
tocContact.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, over6);

function over(e:Event):void {
 tocProduction.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over1(e:Event):void {
 tocWardrobe.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over2(e:Event):void {
 tocMakeup.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over3(e:Event):void {
 tocIllustrators.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over4(e:Event):void {
 tocSpecialfx.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over5(e:Event):void {
 tocAssisting.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
function over6(e:Event):void {
 tocContact.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
```

Comment: Rather than setting all the alpha values to 0, you could use TweenMax.from.

Answer (score 3):

Use a base class that inherits from (what looks like) a `MovieClip`, set the constructor to do the common init and use variables for the dynamic parts (such as what looks like the tween duration).

Another thing you can do is merge the event listeners:

```
tocProduction.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocWardrobe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocMakeup.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocIllustrators.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocSpecialfx.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocAssisting.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);
tocContact.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, overHandler);

function overHandler(event:Event):void {
 event.target.gotoAndPlay("over");
}
```

Comment: This is the better way of doing it.

Answer (score 2):

Sure. Push them into an array, and then do something like:

```
for(var i in myArr) {
    var o = myArr[i];
    o.alpha=0;
    o.x = 400;
    TweenMax.to(o, 1, {alpha:1, easy:Circ.easeIn});
    o.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_OVER, function(e:Event) {e.target.gotoAndPlay("over");});
}
```